# Translating "You always have a choice" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Can someone please help me with a translation?

I would like to translate the phrase "You always have a choice" to Latin.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Meech! Where do you want to use the phrase and have you tried translating it yourself? Context helps find the most suitable translation for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

*Semper est optio* 'always (there) is an option', will suit most circumstances. If you wish, it can be personalised by adding a singular pronoun, as in *Tibi est semper optio*; you may also replace *tibi* by *vobis* if addressing more than one person.